# Capturing Copy Folder Command in Outlook

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I want to

1. Locate and select an email in the Outlook Explorer
2. Right-click the selected email and hover over the "Move" option in the resulting context menu
3. In the resulting submenu of the "Move" option, select (click) the "Copy to Folder" option
4. In the "Copy Items dialog, select a folder and click the "OK" button

   ```
   //The example below displays the "Select Folder dialog".
    set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
   Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
   set SelectFoldersDialog = Session.GetSelectFoldersDialog
   if SelectFoldersDialog.Display Then
    set Folder = SelectFoldersDialog.SelectedFolder
   MsgBox "selected folder: " & Folder.Name
   End If
   ```

   But I did not find way to Capture Ok button event. Is anyway to capture this event ?

Thanks in Advance

Shyam

Comment: What do you mean by "Capture above event" What event?

Comment: Actually, I want to capture http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOSelectFoldersDialog.htm, Session.GetSelectFoldersDialog result . I need to handle popup of folder dialog when user hit copy to folder sub context menu of move .

Comment: I need to capture  RDOSelectFoldersDialog events .

Comment: Redemption does nto use Outlook's menu - the two are completely separate. There is no event that fires when you select "Move" from a popup menu.

Comment: Why do you need to capture the Ok button on the dialog for choosing folders?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no trivial way to capture the Ok button click on the dialog window. The Outlook object mode (nor Redemption) doesn't provide anything for that.